# Angular 2 - disable change detection

Tags: angular

Hello I have component for chat messages. I have a problem with change detection. When I typed, ngFor directive still redraws all messages. I would like to draw messages when I displayed this component and then after I added new message. Here is my code:

**chat.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-chat',
    templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {
    text: string;
    @Input() messages: ChatMessage[];
    @Output() onChanged: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
    constructor(private app: App, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.messages = !this.messages ? [] : this.messages;        
    }

    onChangeHandler(value: string) {
        this.onChanged.emit(value);
    }

    trackByFn(index, item){
        console.log(index, item); //still calls when typing
        return item.Id;
    }
}

export interface ChatMessage {
    Text: string;
}
```

**chat.component.html:**

```
<form action="#" method="post" *ngIf="!readonly" [style.margin-bottom]="'10px'">
    <div class="img-push" [ngClass]="{'input-group': enableSaveButton}">
        <textarea class="form-control input-sm" rows="2" style="resize:none" [(ngModel)]="text" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
         (ngModelChange)="onChangeHandler($event)"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="box-body box-comments pre-scrollable">
    <ng-container *ngIf="messages.length != 0">
        <div class="box-comment" *ngFor="let message of messages; let i=index;trackBy:trackByFn">
            <div class="comment-text">
                <pre>{{message.Text}}</pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Which Angular version do you use? I know you have written 2 in the title but people still sometimes refer to newer versions of Angular as Angular 2.

Comment: What is the condition which decides if this component is to be displayed?

Comment: @DanMacák I have angular in version 4.0.0

Comment: @Abhi `<my-chat [messages]="data.Messages" (onChanged)="hasChanges($event)" *ngIf="data.Messages"/>`

Comment: Check `data.Messages` variable. `*ngIf="data.Messages"` is probably making your component visible even if it is `[]`. You probably want to formulate a different condition to make your component visible. If you want to not display this component until user actually enters a new message, then you will have to compare the lengths of the `message` array. Basically, you have to make your component visible at accurate event.

Comment: @Abhi I need to display chat component when data.Messages is empty because otherwise the input for the new message would not be visible. I think there isnt this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried exactly your code snippet and found out that the elements under the rule of `*ngFor` **are not being rerendered**. The `trackByFn` function is still being called while changing the text, but only as a part of `ngDoCheck` call in `NgForOf` directive, which is a directive that gets automatically created when you use `*ngFor`.

You can verify that in Chrome in devtools in the DOM inspector. If the elements are being rerendered, you see roughly the same as here [image] (taken from [this article](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5))